# laravel eloquent ->whereHas - write your own exists( subquery )

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, exists

Laravel Eloquent `->whereHas()` uses an`exists()` subquery - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html - in order to return your results.

I would like to write my own subquery, but I do not know how to tell Eloquent to ->where it.

If I do:

```
$query->where( DB::raw(' exists( subquery ) ')
```

Laravel instead writes the subquery as:

```
where exists( subquery ) is null
```

So I'm just wondering what `$query->method()` could be used to add an exists() subquery to the 'where' statements.  The subquery would be just the same kind that laravel generates, but written out:

```
... and exists ( select * from `tbl` inner join `assets` on `custom_assets`.`id` = `tbl`.`asset_id` where `assets`.`deleted_at` is null and `users`.`id` = `assets`.`client_id` and `field_id` = ? and (`value` = ? and `assets`.`deleted_at` is null )
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a subquery you want to write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`whereRaw()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#raw-expressions):

```
$query->whereRaw('exists( subquery )')
```

Answer (score 1):

[Read WhereHas Description Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

You can find this code example there. You can also add a closure for you custom query in whereHas.

```
// Retrieve all posts with at least one comment containing words like foo%
$posts = App\Post::whereHas('comments', function ($query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
})->get();
```